# Python regex search, match mismatch

Tags: python, regex, mismatch

I'm trying to check syntax of input file, where are rules for my project.

I want to check if that would be right or not. So I have my regex

```
\s*.*\$\s*..*\$\s*\|}\s*.*\s*,*
```

Which finds this text:

```
sometimes $so$ |} hello,
life $good$ |} hello, 
not $that$ |} hello
```

Now in python I'm using re.findall to find the correct text, join the found patterns and then I compare it with the length of starting text. But for some reason it doesn't work.

The code: `rule_syntax_check = re.findall("\s*.*\$\s*..*\$\s*\|}\s*.*\s*,*", RULES, re.DOTALL)`

For example that would lead to error:

```
sometimes $so$ |} hello,
life $good$ |  } hello, 
not $that$ |} hello
```

But it finds the second line too, so the number of characters is the same as the number of found characters by my `findall`. Is there any other option, or what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is exactly that you are using [`re.DOTALL`](https://regex101.com/r/eS4gZ3/1) a.k.a `S` flag. `DOTALL` means that the dot matches even newlines; if you [take it out](https://regex101.com/r/sC6dF8/1), the match cannot span to a new line.

---

However a better solution would be to test each record separately; e.g., if they are separated by comma, you'd first split by `,`, then use `re.match` to match a single rule against the regular expression. Note that `re.match` is not anchored to the end of the string, so you need to add extra `$` to make sure that match against the exact string is required (though it is not necessary here):

Something like:

```
rules_split = RULES.split(',')
for i in rules_split:
    if not re.match(r'\s*.*\$\s*.+\$\s*\|}.*$')
```